# Call a C/C++ function in Java Spring Maven web application

Tags: java, c++, c, spring, java-native-interface

I am a java developer and I have developed a web application for live video streaming in Java Spring and maven framework. I am trying to integrating the face recognition code with the existing web application. The face recognition code is in c language and I need to call those c functions in the java code. Can anybody guide me how to use this c code into a java web application? I have explored over the net regarding this but found nothing appropriate regarding this. I know JNI may works for this but how to integrate with web application?

I hope my requirement is clear;

> (Spring+Hibernate+Maven) + (C-language code) -> web application

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~dinov/courses_students.dir/04/Winter/STAT130D.dir/STAT130D_notes.dir/JNI_C_example.html

Comment: Thanks Pumpkin, This is a manual process and I am looking for an automated process for the web application.

Comment: @Pumpkin 's link is the most likely way for doing so. Alternatively, you can compile the C program independently and run it from within your java program as a child process using System.exec(). You can communicate with the child by connecting to its standard pipes (stdin and stdout) using Process.getInputStream() and Process.getOutputStream(). I do this in reverse in one of my projects to make a java program to be the UI for a C program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class that loads a library from the System object like this:

```
public class MyLibrary {
    static { System.loadLibrary("mylib"); }
    public static native boolean foo();
    public static native String bar();
}
```

You then have access to those methods like `MyLibrary.foo()`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Could you please tell me how to load the mylib in the MyLibrary class? If you have any simple tutorial for this please share.

Comment: The code shown does this. Replace `mylib` with the full name of your library. `System.loadLibrary()` loads the library into the class.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Do I have to use JNA or does Java supports this out of the box?